# Is there a way to set QImage resolution according to the Drawn Contents?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qimage

I am trying to make a program in Qt/C++ which makes basic Class Diagrams from C++ code. To show output, I chose to print the diagrams on a QImage using QPainter. However, I have no way of knowing how much space (width * height) will be required for the provided code. 
I tried to first draw image on a 5000x5000 QImage and then 'scale' it to the required dimensions but after the scaling, text(which is also Drawn using QPainter::drawText) on the QImage becomes impossible to read. Is there a way to either EXPAND QImage as needed or if not possible kindly suggest some other workaround.

I am pretty new to Qt so kindly be as elaborate as possible.

**RELEVANT CODE PIECES:**

```
QImage temp_img(5000,5000, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QImage final_img = temp_img.scaled(800, l_y+30,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

**l_y** is the end height of the printed diagram.

Comment: Why do you do the extra QImage step, what do you do with the QImage?

Comment: @hyde i draw the initial diagram on a 5k * 5k QImage so that the space doesnt run  out then i scale it according to contents and save it in a new file. Used two files for the intention of comparing results only.

Comment: If final image's resolution differs from the one you get before scaling there's no surprise you are getting unreadable mess out of your text. I suggest you either work on how your diagram is drawn on a fixed size image, or try to calculate resolution of your diagram to truly keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: Why do you need to scale the image down? Why not produce at the save resolution directly?

Comment: You should really not scale bitmap (pixel) images, like ever, if you can avoid it (and here you haven't yet told us what is the compelling reason to scale it in this case). Produce the bitmap image directly at target resolution. And if you need to print it on a printer, use the QPainter for printing, do not produce intermediate bitmap then either.

Comment: Also, instead of bitmaps, consider using this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvggenerator.html

Comment: I am trying to scale image so that the final output is more user-friendly as no one will like to have extra space hanging on the sides of their output. Moreover, with a higher res than required, i have to zoom in to read text. I'll look into SVGs @hyde

Comment: Ok, let me put the question the other way. Why do you want to produce the higher resolution image, and then scale it down, why these two steps, what do you mean to achieve with 2 steps? Also, what do you mean by "extra space"? When you say you want to scale your image, do you actually mean you want to *crop* it (probably with [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy))?

Comment: @hyde YES! I want to crop the excess space.

Comment: @hyde your method to crop the image using QImage::copy did the trick. Kindly post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not scaling image, that is changing the pixels (scaling down by combining several pixels, or scaling up by adding pixels). What you want to do is just remove parts of image, also known as *cropping* the image. Or to say it the other way, you want to copy part of the image, leaving unneeded parts behind.

You can achieve this using [`QImage::copy` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#copy).

---

As a side note, since your image is really a line drawing (I assume), consider using a vector image format, so viewer can scale the image freely. Qt has [`QSvgGenerator` class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvggenerator.html) which can do this.